# Execute Select query on Mysql table over 300 million rows(hit no index) using multiple threads?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, multithreading

**ABSTRACT**

I aim to read data from database A, do some extra processing, then insert
the new one into database B. Because the data size is extremely large, I
can barely read them all at once, then I slice them into several pieces and
spawn multiple threads to read and process.

**DESCRIPTION**

The table schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_order_record` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `remark` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `idx_order_id` (`order_id`)
)
```

1. `id` - primary key
2. `order_id` - unique identity of an order
3. `status` - status of an order, e.g., `status=3` means order already delivered
4. `remark` - extra comment
5. `created_at` - creation time of the record, also means creation time of the current status

I only care about the orders delivered during specific range days, in other words, the orders satisfied:

1. `created_at` [image: belongsto] [from_date, to_date)
2. `status` = 3

As a result, the final SQL may as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_order_record` WHERE `status`=3
    AND `created_at` >= DATE('2016-06-01') AND `created_at` < DATE('2016-06-02');
```

Its not over yet. Even the SQL filters `created_at` [image: belongsto] ['2016-06-01', '2016-06-02'), a single day! The result magnitude is still nearly 3 million, too large to fetch the total at a time.

Then I get an idea and split the query criteria `created_at` into several shorter periods:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... AND `created_at` >= '2016-06-01 00:00:00' AND `created_at` < '2016-06-01 02:00:00';
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... AND `created_at` >= '2016-06-01 02:00:00' AND `created_at` < '2016-06-01 04:00:00';
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... AND `created_at` >= '2016-06-01 04:00:00' AND `created_at` < '2016-06-01 06:00:00';
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... AND `created_at` >= '2016-06-01 06:00:00' AND `created_at` < '2016-06-01 08:00:00';

...

SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... AND `created_at` >= '2016-06-01 22:00:00' AND `created_at` < '2016-06-02 00:00:00';
```

And execute them in parallel by spawn the same amount of threads, each thread execute a single selection. It's just
in vain, however, no actual improvements have been made and even have a negative impact on the database performance
overall. As it says, *A Bad Apple Can Spoil The Whole Barrel*.

**QUESTIONS**

I consult our DBA and he told me in view of such a huge table, executing `Select` query with no index and multiple
threads is equivalent to suicide. But my questions are:

1. I know such `Select` queries are slow queries since every single `Select` query has to search the entire table(iterates
   over 300 million rows, according to the `EXPLAIN` command) before it could return what I want. But why multi-threading
   doesn't work and even make it worse? What's the corresponding internal principal of MySql?
2. How to improve? For some reasons, I have to filter by these two syllables `status` and `created_at`. If this is a
   prerequisite, would there still be any advice to make some improvements?

I will appreciate very much!

Comment: Why not just accept the sage advice from your in-house DBA and put a good old-fashioned index on the `created_at` column?

Comment: Actually the first thing I thought is also putting index on `created_at`, however, such an operation would lock the table for hours because of the tremendous data size and affect other business units' access to this table for too long. Therefore, dba refused the requirement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen idk, maybe ask the users how much they like the wait right now

Answer (score 0):

> I know such Select queries are slow queries since every single Select
>   query has to search the entire table(iterates over 300 million rows,
>   according to the EXPLAIN command) before it could return what I want.
>   But why multi-threading doesn't work and even make it worse? What's
>   the corresponding internal principal of MySql?

Because even though you are trying to fetch small amount of data from a large table MySql **HAS** to go thru the entire table for EACH of those divided queries. It also cant CACHE the recent data due to size. So in effect you are hitting MySQL "N" Times simultaneously  because thats what parallelism does.

Your simplest solution is to follow your DBA's advice.

EDIT:
Just saw your comment about index taking long to create. Other option is to Create a New backup table index it when done switch (rename).

Comment: @streethacker when are the rows deleted from this table ? or are they permanent residents? Is there a SP that is inserting and deleting rows from this table?

Comment: no physical delete operation is allowed, replaced by regular database archive and the table maintains recent 6 months' records. insert operation keeps happening, because each time the order status change will create a new record. @objectNotFound

Comment: Make that insert **Simultaneously** write to a new table which has theindex . In 6 months you will have a table which is indexed and you can swap. I know this may not be feasible but its the least disruptive solution. 300mil isnt too big these days. See if you can play with the data on a test server to see how long it takes to index it, BTW Whats the table size in GB  for that table ?

Comment: The total size of this table is more than 55GB @objectNotFound